# What smart pointer type do I need if I want to release the memory when re-pointing the pointer?

Tags: c++, qt

I have a instance variable to a class which will contain the current object that that class-object is working on.

```
class something {
    base* _currentOperation;
}
```

The operation is signaling when it is done, a signal that I just transfer to the class that is the owner of the current classobject. Then I create a new operation and assign the _currentOperation-pointer to that one. Is there any pointer type that releases the memory when you redirect the pointer or should I just call "deleteLater()" before assigning it to the new object?

And if I used a QPointer here for example, due to the long term storange and that I dont want dangeling pointers, how can I store a derived type in it?

Also, could anyone give me a example of a QSharedPointer where you can store Derived classes? And how do I pass it to other functions and when will it be realease? Tried to find doc but they never really show any code how you actually can use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are not going to have multiple owners of the pointer you want to use `QScopedPointer`.  `QScopedPointer` assumes responsibility for the pointer and will destroy it when the `QScopedPointer` instance is destroyed.  Check out the [documentation](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/qscopedpointer.html#dtor.QScopedPointer) for detailed info.

Creating a new pointer

```
    QScopedPointer<base> _currentOperation;
```

If you do not provide a pointer to the constructor it defaults to `0`. _currentOperation can assume responsibility for any object of type `base` or any derived type of `base` just like a normal pointer (don't forget to use virtual destructors).

When you want to set `_currentOperation` to a new pointer use

```
    _currentOperation.reset( the_new_pointer );
```

The `reset` operation will first destroy the object `QScopedPointer` currently owns, then take ownership of `the_new_pointer`.

There are several ways to pass around the pointer.  You can either pass the `QScopedPointer` by reference or if you know (though not recommended unless necessary) the object will not be deleted while the calling function is using it you can pass the pointer by calling `_currentOperation.data()`

Comment: is it really good to passa a scoped pointer by ref? if i want to pass it and use it by many i should use a shared pointer? atm im using qpointer, will that autorelese it when repointing?

Comment: @chikuba It depends on what you mean by "pass it and use it by many."  If several class instances will own their own copy of the pointer than you want to use QSharedPointer. QSharedPointer will ensure that as long as one copy of the QSharedPointer<base> is in existence the pointer will be valid. 

However, if the pointer is owned by a single instance and "used by many" means you pass it to several functions that only use the pointer during their execution then passing a QScopedPointer by ref is the correct option.

Comment: @chikuba `QPointer` will not release an object when it is destroyed. `QPointer` is used for creating a guarded pointer to an object owned by someone else.     `QObject myObject;` ... `QPointer pNotMyObject = &myObject;`      If `myObject` is destroyed `pNotMyObject` will be set to 0 (null). However, `myObject` will not be affected if `pNotMyObject` is destroyed.

Comment: atm i have all my pointers in scoped ones except the ones i dont create or own, then i keep them in a qpointer just to be able to check so that its still valid. also, when i allocate memory i do it within a scopedpointer and then ship it as a raw pointer (take()) to whatever class that will be the new owner to it (who will then store it in a scoped pointer). any issue with that approach?

Comment: Sounds reasonable.  If you control the interfaces I would suggest one little tweak.  I would pass the QScopedPointer and allow the new owner to call `take()`. This minimaizes the amount of time the "raw" pointer is not being controlled.  For example, If an exception occurs after calling `take()` but before the new owner takes control the pointer would not be deleted.

Answer (score 1):

Resettable smart pointers typically do release the resource (memory) when they are reset (pointed to something else).  Otherwise they wouldn't be very smart!

Comment: so any kind that is? auto, shared, scoped?

Comment: All three of those, yes.  There may be others that don't work this way, but I think that would be unusual.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you're after is [QScopedPointer](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qscopedpointer.html). Also my [answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9129131/594137) might help you.